# Getting a numeric vallue out of a mixed string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on a formula to calculate the check digit from a VIN number; 17 alphanumeric characters, each with its own value (numbers have their own value, letters are designated a value between 1 and 9). Unfortunately, extracting the characters individually using `MID` extracts numbers as text, giving me an error in the `VLOOKUP`.

I initially tried to just use `MID([@[VIN / Cargo ID]]; 1;1)` (incrementing the start number for each character in the string), which works fine as long as the targeted character is a letter. If it's a number, however, it gets extracted as text, which causes the lookup to fail.

I've tried converting them to numeric values using an `IF(ISNUMBER) ... NUMBERVALUE` combination, and I've tried storing the match column in my lookup table as Text, without success.

My current attempt is based on this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MID([@[VIN / Cargo ID]]; 1;1)); NUMBERVALUE(MID([@[VIN / Cargo ID]]; 1;1)); VLOOKUP(MID([@[VIN / Cargo ID]]; 1;1); VIN_charval; 2; FALSE))
```

That doesn't work either, giving `#N/A`. Anyone have any ideas that could help?

For clarity, the specific construction of the VIN isn't an issue; the problem is specifically in extracting numbers from *any* alphanumeric text string.

Comment: Please include some sample VIN numbers, for those who might not know what they look like.

Comment: And please also include some expected output with those sample VIN numbers.

Comment: The question isn't about the VIN checksum itself, but about getting a single character, either alphabetical or numeric, out of a 17-character alphanumeric string. They can look like any combination of 17 letters and number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the structure of the VIN is fixed ie normally 17 alphanumeric characters, you can get the characters you need by position using MID(), see:

[image]

As MID() outputs text, you will note I have multiplied by 1 to make sure that it is a number.

I just took 2 characters starting at position 6, but you can change that...

Comment: `MID` is what I'd been using - but multiplying by one did the trick, thanks! I combined it in and used `=IF(ISNUMBER(MID([@[VIN / Cargo ID]]; 1;1)*1); MID([@[VIN / Cargo ID]]; 1;1)*1; VLOOKUP(MID([@[VIN / Cargo ID]]; 1;1); VIN_charval; 2; FALSE))` - which seems to work for both letters and numbers.

Comment: Nice to see you applied it to your situation, glad it helped.